# onContextItemSelected : id clicked is not the good one

Tags: android, android-menu

I have an error somewhere in my code because when i click on an item in a contextual menu, it doesn't refer to the good id.

In fact, i inflate a different menu xml file following the value of "etat" String.

**onCreateContextMenu :**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        // Get the list
        ListView list = (ListView)v;

        // Get the list item position    
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        int position = info.position;

        // Now you can do whatever.. (Example, load different menus for different items)
        Annonce ann = (Annonce) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String etat = ann.getEtat();
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        if (etat.equalsIgnoreCase("confirm")) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_confirm, menu);
        }
        else if (etat.equalsIgnoreCase("online")) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_online, menu);
        }
        else if (etat.equalsIgnoreCase("offline")) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_offline, menu);
        }


    }
```

The code of **onContextItemSelected** :

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int index = info.position;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_confirm_apercu:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_confirm_supprimer:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_online_apercu:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_online_horsligne:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_online_supprimer:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_offline_apercu:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_offline_putonline:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_offline_supprimer:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**R.menu.menu_confirm :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_confirm_apercu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Aperçu de l'annonce"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_confirm_supprimer"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Supprimer l'annonce"/>

</menu>
```

**R.menu.menu_offline**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_offline_apercu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Aperçu de l'annonce"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_offline_supprimer"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Supprimer l'annonce"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_offline_putonline"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Remettre l'annonce en ligne"/>

</menu>
```

**R.menu.menu_online :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_online_apercu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Aperçu de l'annonce"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_online_supprimer"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Supprimer l'annonce"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_online_horsligne"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Passer l'annonce hors ligne"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: What do you get as the `info.position` when bring the menu for one of the rows? Do you have headers/footers set on `ListView`?

Comment: @Luksprog I get the position of the item which have been clicked in the listview

Comment: @Luksprog But these line is not needed. index is not used in the function.

Comment: Can you make the question clear? You say that *"it doesn't refer to the good id."* but in the comment above you say that info.position does refer to the proper position of the item that was clicked to get the menu. Which one is it?